# Unique constraint only when two columns are duplicated in a row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, constraints

I have a voting table which contains the company name of the user who has been voted on and the unique customer number of the user who voted on the company.

users vote (upvote or downvote) on other companies and have to provide their unique customer number to vote.

I want to create a unique constraint which allows the user to only vote once but cannot vote twice on the same Company however I want it to be that the same customer number can vote on multiple queries. I only know of the unique constraint but this doesn't work because it will only allow the user to vote once on ANY company as it activates the unique constraint.

For Example (this would be all good):

```
CompanyID  Voted(customer number)
Maccas     12345
BMW        12345
Maccas     66666
```

and I want to constrain the following (by activating a constraint when both company name and customer number are the same):

```
CompanyID  Voted
Maccas     12345
Maccas     12345 (should prevent duplicate of both columns co-existing)
```

My Code:

```
string voteTable = "INSERT INTO dbo.votes (CompanyID,Voted) Values (@CompanyID,@Voted)";

canUserVote(); //checks if customer number exists

                        this.companyName = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);

                        SqlCommand insertVoterDetails = new SqlCommand (voteTable,voteDb); //inserts voter details to votes table
                        insertVoterDetails.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", this.companyName);
                        insertVoterDetails.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voted", custVoteTextBox.Text);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can create constraints on both columns. This can be done in the database: What database do you use?

Comment: I'm referring to creating a constraint when both columns are duplicate to other rows, not a single column. i'm using MSSQL, Thanks

Comment: See answer of Goel below.

Comment: @JamesS .. Do you need anything else? See my answer below..

Comment: Thanks guys! It all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created your table then add a composite primary key in following manner..

```
CREATE TABLE Voting
(
  [CompanyID] INT NOT NULL,
  [Voted] INT NOT NULL

  CONSTRAINT PK_CompanyVote PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([CompanyID], [Voted])
)
```

or as follows

```
create table Voting (
     CompanyID integer not null,
     Voted integer not null,
     primary key (CompanyID, Voted)
);
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac8c1/1) and following is the whole code for you. Here I have created basic `company, user and company user` table, and inserted some dummy records.

**Note**: I have imposed foreign key constraints as well to make sure that you are inserting right values. However if you want then you can leave this part.

**Create tables**

```
create table C
(
CompanyID int primary key,
CompanyName varchar(50)
);

Create table U
(
UserID int primary key,
UserName varchar(50)
);

Create table CU
(
CompanyID int,
UserID int,
FOREIGN KEY (CompanyID) REFERENCES C(CompanyID),
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES U(UserID),
primary key (CompanyID, UserID)
);
```

**Insert statements**

```
Insert into c values (101,'Google')
Insert into c values (102,'Yahoo')
Insert into c values (103,'Microsoft')

Insert into U values (1001,'Mike')
Insert into U values (1002,'John')
Insert into U values (1003,'Hanis')

Insert into CU values (101,1001)
Insert into CU values (101,1002)
Insert into CU values (102,1002)
```

When I fired following query then I got an error as well, which is expected in your case.

```
Insert into CU values (102,1002)
```

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK__CU__FCEF90863A56FFA3'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.CU'. The duplicate key value is (102, 1002). The statement
>   has been terminated.